# How to run methods without freezing animation?

Tags: python, animation

I'm building a VR app prototype in Blender and using bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre for events updates.

Some methods take few seconds to calculate. Is it possible to run them in parallel without freezing animation flow?

I simplified the code to show what I'm trying to achieve

```
import bpy
import time

list = []

def calculate_new_location():
    # after a lot of vector math and matrix transformations
    # this method updates the list of locations for per frame animation
    time.sleep(5)
    list.append((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    list.append((0.5, 0.0, 0.0))
    list.append((1.0, 0.0, 0.0)) 

def run_main_loop(scene): 
    current_frame = scene.frame_current +1
    # let's pretend that user did something on frame 5 
    # and we need to recalculate some object location 
    if current_frame == 5:
        calculate_new_location()
    # if list is updated we animate a new object location for the next frame
    if len(list) > 0:
        obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
        obj.location = list[0]
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=current_frame + 1)
        list.pop(0)  

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(run_main_loop)
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

Or maybe there is a different way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: `time.sleep(5)` waits for 5 seconds: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.sleep - removing this line will probably solve your issue.

Comment: If you added the sleep to simulate extensive calculations - you can run a process and communicate with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188389/communicating-with-a-running-process

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes. This line emulates "a lot of vector math and matrix transformations" which I throw away to simplify code example.
What I need is some kind of callback of multiprocessing solution that will allow me to use the return of this method later.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to learn more about how subprocess works in Blender

Comment: An important question is: do you want to wait for the calculations to finish (in which case the script is good as it is), do you want to schedule that work (in which case you need to save somewhere all data that will not be available later), or do you want to e.g. calculate as much as possible in a given time limit (e.g. for each frame you can start calculating stuff for the next frame and read what was calculated for current frame and use that) then a separate process might be the way to go...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  This question is getting close votes because it lacks details or clarity.  You can edit your question and it will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.